# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure The project should have the name

Tags: jenkins, svn, build

I am new to working with Jenkins and faced the following problem: I need to add a Java project to SVN-repository, then this project is automatically loaded into the jenkins account to which I was given access.
Jenkins is hosted on the remote server and I can't change any configuration there but only run builds and so on.
After I add a project to the repository, it appears in Jenkins with "failed" status.
The console output is as follows:

[image]

Project structure in SVN-repository:

[image]

In Jenkins has structure:

[image]

Tell me, please, what could be the problem and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
+ /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/jtl/checkProjectName.sh Practice1
The project should have the name Practice1
```

Currently you're checking out in `workspace` directory. Try to checkout your repository from `workspace/Practice1` directory.

Comment: Jenkins is hosted on the remote server and I can't change any configuration there but only run builds and so on.